# Make two factories return the same object that implements both interfaces

Tags: oop, factory, multiple-inheritance

(I use C# in my examples, but this question is not specifically about C#.)

We have factories to create objects for multiple interfaces, one factory per interface.

Say we have a `PrintingFactory` to create an object implementing `IPrinting` and a `ScanningFactory` for `IScanning`. We have concrete printers implementing `IPrinting` and concrete scanners implementing `IScanning` and the factories decide which implementation is chosen.

In `ScanningFactory` I have:

```
public static IScanning Build() 
{
    ...
    return new CanonXYZ2000();
}
```

I have similar code in `PrintingFactory`, and in `main` I have:

```
scanner = ScanningFactory.Build();
printer = PrintingFactory.Build();
```

---

Now, what happens if I want to instantiate one object that implements both interfaces?

```
public class CanonXYZ2001MultiPurpose: IPrinting, IScanning {...}
```

I would like both factories to return the same object. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you are asking if CanonXYZ2001MultiPurpose can be created by both ScanningFactory and PrintingFactory ?

In this case both factories can return instances of CanonXYZ2001MultiPurpose with no issues, since this class implements both interfaces:

Scanning factory code:

```
public static IScanning Build() 
{
    ...
    return new CanonXYZ2001MultiPurpose ();
}
```

Printing factory code:

```
public static IPrinting Build() 
{
    ...
    return new CanonXYZ2001MultiPurpose ();
}
```

Both variables now hold instance of CanonXYZ2001MultiPurpose:

```
var scanner = ScanningFactory.Build();
var printer = PrintingFactory.Build();
```

Comment: That's what I have and it creates two objects where I only want one. One is instantiated by scanning factory and returned as a scanner, and then another one is instantiated by printing factory and returned as a printer.

In the factories, I know under what circumstances we create a multipurpose machine, it's just that the two factories need some mechanism to access the object that the other maybe already instantiated. I want to keep `main` in the dark about this, `main` only wants to scan and print, it doesn't care about the details.

Comment: In this case you could use single factory, which accepts desired type and returns appropriate instance. Internally it can hold list of specific factories for each type. Also you need to keep track of all instances you already created.

When the Build(Type t) is called you can check if you already have any instance that matches your requirements (e.g. implements both IPrinting and IScanning). If you have such instance - you return it, otherwise you simply call appropriate factory for specific type, store this instance internally and return it back to the calling party.